# Keyboard and mouse don't work when live booting from USB on MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, mac

I burned the Ubuntu image on my USB and whenever it boots on my Mac the keyboard and the mouse do not work. As a matter of fact, the same thing happened when I try to boot Arch Linux or BlackArch, but surprisingly they all work fine on my friend's older Mac from 2014. I suppose it might have something to do with the drivers.

Has anybody experienced the same problem?

Here is the error message I am getting:
[image: error message when booting]

Here are my Mac specifications: 
[image: my Mac specifications]